# Reload a Div with jquery timer

Tags: jquery

I am trying to refresh a div on a page with the server name the page is being displayed from.  This is just for test so we can test what happens when a auth cookie times out.  I want to do this with jquery but I can't seem to get anything working.  I found an example online that I have been working on but keep getting errors with it as well.

We have an html page on each of our servers that just contains the server name.  It is the text from that page that we want displayed in the div.

Below is the code sample that I found.  Can someone help me?  I'm pretty new to jquery.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery.timers-1.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var j = jQuery.noConflict();
        j(document).ready(function () {
            j(".refreshMe").everyTime(5000, function (i) {
                j.ajax({
                    url: "refresh.html",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (html) {
                        j(".refreshMe").html(html);
                    }
                })
            })
        });
        j('.refreshMe').css({ color: "red" });
    });
</script>
```

`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var interval = 500;   //number of mili seconds between each call
    var refresh = function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "path/to/server/page.php",
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $('#server-name').html(html);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    refresh();
                }, interval);
            }
        });
    };
    refresh();
});

<div id="server-name"></div>
```

So what is happening?

I will call `refresh` once the page is ready, then an ajax call is made to `path/to/server/page.php` which will return the desired result.

I show the results in `div#server-name` then I do a `setTimeout` which will call `refresh` again every `interval` mili seconds.

Comment: It might be best to use a synchronous call instead of $.ajax.  The asynchronous calls could get out of sync pretty quickly depending on response times.

Comment: Well, that's works great in the little HTML page I created to test it.  However, it doesn't want to work in the aspx page that I actually need to run it in.  I will keep playing with it and see if I can get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Rhonda,

Here's another example that you could try.  Are you using MVC or ASP.NET WebForms?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var timer = setInterval( updateDiv, 5000);
            var counter = 0;  //only here so we can see that the div is being updated if the same error is thrown

            function updateDiv() {
                var messageDiv = $('#content');
                $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        async: false,
                        url: "your.site.com/path/page.ext",
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(result) {
                            counter++;
                            messageDiv.empty();
                            messageDiv.append(result);
                            messageDiv.append("<br />");
                            messageDiv.append("counter = " + counter);
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                            counter++;
                            messageDiv.empty();
                            messageDiv.append("thrown error: " + thrownError);
                            messageDiv.append("<br />");
                            messageDiv.append("status text: " + xhr.statusText);
                            messageDiv.append("<br />");
                            messageDiv.append("counter = " + counter);
                        }
                });
            }   

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Div is below here</h2>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can shortcut the code to update the DIV by using .html, but I wanted to break it out so it was clear.